# change item positioning when something's hovered

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

So, I have a vertical navbar on the left side of my page, and I've made it from small to big when it's hovered. Basically, from only showing icons to also showing a couple words, standard stuff. But, the way it works, when it extends, it grows over the rest of the website. Is there a way I can make it resize the rest of the website too (only when hovered) so it doesnt hide any content?
layout looks like this:

```html
<body>
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div id="content">
    <main>
      <div></div>
      <img />
      <div></div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

when the navbar is focused, I want div#content to be shrunk by 11rem (so that the expanded navbar isnt on top of div#content).

navbar is 5rem when not in focus, and 16rem when in focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need JavaScript for this.
Try the following:

```js
let nav = document.getElementById("nav");
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let contentWidth = content.getBoundingClientRect().width;

nav.addEventListener("mouseover", mOver, false);
nav.addEventListener("mouseout", mOut, false);

function mOver() {
  content.style.width = `calc(${contentWidth}px - 11rem)`;
}

function mOut() {  
     content.style.width = contentWidth + 'px';
}
```

```css
#nav{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

.content{
/* Just a sample width for demonstration */ 
width:20rem; 
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <navbar id="nav">NavBar: Hover Here</navbar>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <main>
      <div></div>
      <img />
      <div></div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```